# How does civicrm handle automatically generated 'Unsubscribe' messages from google

Tags: civimail, bounce

Asking because in looking at some other bounce issues I notice a bunch of emails such as

> Unsubscribe - This message was automatically generated by Gmail

in INBOX/CiviMail/ignored

and just wondering if this is the expected behaviour

Comment: Do you get the same behaviour for unsubscribes from iOS Mail?: `iOS Mail sent this email to unsubscribe from the message “Mail Subject”.` I suppose that is the same mechanism and this is working fine for us. It seems like we don't have enough reputation with gmail to have the quick unsubscribe option displayed there.

Comment: I've seen this type of thing elsewhere too. In another non-Civi system we use the List-Unsubscribe header to include a link, but gmail seems to ignore the link. They describe it here at the following link in step 3, but the unsubscribe link they present to users always seems to be mailto regardless. https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126?hl=en

Comment: Actually I'm just noticing this part of RFC 8058: "The List-Unsubscribe and List-Unsubscribe-Post headers MUST be covered by the signature and included in the "h=" tag of a valid DKIM-Signature header field." That might be why it ignores the link.